# Is there a better way to include extension to my standard autodesk forge web interface?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

Currently we are working on trying to implement an extension to our autodesk forge webpage. We cloned the extension from github and used npm install in our command prompt as a setup. As found online the next step is to include the extension in our main javascript script. Unfortunately the extension is not visualised no matter how hard we try. Do you guys have any tips or solutions? Thank you in advance!

```
var viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer'); 
viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerElement, { 
    extensions: ['BasicExtension'] 
});
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function () { 
    viewer.start(); loadDocument(viewer, options.document); 
});
```

Comment: We tried to include this in our code: 


Load extensions when viewer is initialized:

  var viewerElement = document.getElementById('viewer');

  viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerElement, {
      extensions: ['BasicExtension']
  });
  

  Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function () {
      viewer.start();
      loadDocument(viewer, options.document);
  });

Comment: Hey @Niels, take that code from your comment and add it into your question between to sets of 3 backticks.  It will be easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you're working on an extension called **MyAwesomeExtension**, implemented in a class of the same name. In order to add the extension to the viewer and have it appear in the toolbar UI, a couple things need to be done:

1. The extension must "register itself" (see the end of the extension skeleton in the [tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/skeleton?id=create-the-extension))

```
Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('MyAwesomeExtension', MyAwesomeExtension);
```

2. Your extension script must be included in the HTML (*after* the viewer script)

```
<script src="/path/to/myawesomeextension.js"></script>
```

3. The name of your extension must be provided during the initialization of `GuiViewer3D`

```
viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('forgeViewer'), { extensions: ['MyAwesomeExtension'] });
```

4. In your extension class, you must override the `onToolbarCreated` method, create your own button, and insert it to the toolbar. Again, see the extension skeleton in the [tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/skeleton?id=create-the-extension)

EDIT:

Here's a [git commit](https://github.com/petrbroz/learn.forge.viewmodels/commit/001f9c5f141d1c80ab13b5eca538820ed86e59ce) that adds a basic extension skeleton on top of the "View your models" Node.js sample code from https://learnforge.autodesk.io.

Comment: Thank you once again. Could you have a look at my code down below and check where you would place these four different steps?

Comment: Sure :) See this [commit](https://github.com/petrbroz/learn.forge.viewmodels/commit/001f9c5f141d1c80ab13b5eca538820ed86e59ce) - it adds a basic extension skeleton on top of the standard [View your models](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewmodels) sample code. Just keep in mind that the sample code uses Forge Viewer version 7.

Comment: Thanks, I did try these steps but now I am struggling with step four. Trying to understand the toolbar part. How would you include this in the script?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. In the git commit you can see that I've added a new script (_js/MyAwesomeExtension.js_), and in the HTML I'm adding the extension script via `<script src="js/MyAwesomeExtension.js"></script>`.

Comment: In the extension class I'm also overriding a method called `onToolbarCreated` - this method is called (with Forge Viewer v7) whenever the official toolbar is created so that your extension can add its own controls (buttons) to it.

Comment: I am trying to implement this Iot extension from the forge.rcdb package. Can I just copy this code and place it into MyAwesomeExtension? It is a bit to complicated for me at the moment [link](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.IoT)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you once again. Could you have a look at my code and check where you would place these four different steps?

[Example of my piece of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia3Sw.png)